# How do you solve $w^4=16(1-w)^4$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Giving you answer in Cartesian form.

$\dfrac{w^4}{(1-w)^4}=16$ Are you supposed to let $w=x+yi$?

> $w^4=x^4+4x^3yi-6x^2y^2-4xiy^3+y^4=16$
>
> I then know that you get routes 2,-2,2i,-2i But I dont know how?
>
> I have done $x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2=16$
>
> and $4x^3yi-4xy^3i=0$ => $x^3y=xy^3$ (which doesn't make sense)
>
> Is this the wrong method?

Comment: If W is the same as w, you can take the fourth root of both sides and solve the resulting linear equation in one variable. Then remember by De Moivre's that there must be 4 fourth roots and use the one you found to find the others.

Comment: In the title you have $(1-w)^4$. In the question you have $1-w^4$. So which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right away, you should see that $w=0$ doesn't work, so observing that $$16(1-w)^4=2^4(1-w)^4=(2-2w)^4,$$ our problem becomes equivalent to $$1=\frac{16(1-w)^4}{w^4}=\frac{(2-2w)^4}{w^4}=\left(\frac{2-2w}w\right)^4=\left(\frac2w-2\right)^4,$$ meaning we need $$\frac2w-2\in\{\pm1,\pm i\}.$$ Finding those $4$ values of $w$ should then be relatively simple.

Comment: I do not understand $16(1-w)^4=2^4(1-w)^4=(2-2w)^4,$ is there a rule I don't know?

Comment: @maxmitch: $$\begin{align}2^4(1-w)^4 &= 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2(1-w)(1-w)(1-w)(1-w)\\ &= 2(1-w)2(1-w)2(1-w)2(1-w)\\ &= (2-2w)(2-2w)(2-2w)(2-2w)\\ &= (2-2w)^4.\end{align}$$ More generally, for any positive integer $n$ and any complex numbers $w,z$, it can be shown that $w^nz^n=(wz)^n$. For $w,z\ne 0$, we can extend that result to $n=0$ and $n<0,$ too. Sadly, when dealing with complex numbers, we can't always do this kind of thing the way we can with positive real numbers and real powers. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities) for more.

Answer (score 5):

Let $z=\dfrac{w}{1-w}$. You get $z^4=16$. Note that $2 ^4=16$. Then you need $z'^4=1$. Solve for $z'$, then roll back.

Comment: I have tried to solve for $z^4$ in my question can you tell me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If $w^{4}=(2(1-w))^{4}$ you have $w^{2}=(2(1-w))^{2}$ or $w^{2}=-(2(1-w))^{2}$. Solve this two quadratic equations and you should get 4 solutions.

Comment: The first of the two quadratics can again be split up by difference of squares into two linear equations, too. Nice approach!

Answer (score 0):

Take a 4th root of both sides (of the question in the title) and $w=2i^\epsilon(1-w)$, where $\epsilon$ can be $0,1,2,3$. Then you just have a linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

It is annoying when the question is changed after an answer has been submitted.
Oh well.

Look at the other answers.

I am answering the question in the
body of the text, not in the title.

From $\frac{w^4}{1-w^4} = 16$,
$w^4 = 16(1-w^4) = 16 - 16 w^4$
or
$17 w^4 = 16$
or
$w = \sqrt[4]{\frac{16}{17}}
=2 \sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{17}}
$.

Now use all the 4-th roots of 1 to get the 4 possible values of $w$.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I usually look to titles and not at bodies! =)